# Yii2- как сохранить названиe $_GET в Url

Tags: yii2

я хочу получить что то вроде этого
http://sitename.com/controllername/actionname/getname/getvalue
более конкретно
http://sitename.com/product/index/id/12

и уже в контроллере Product получить значение id

```
<?php
namespace frontend\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex($id){
        echo $id; //равно 12
    }
}
```

самое главное сохранить названиe **id** в Url
http://sitename.com/product/index/**id**/12

заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтоб получились красивые урлы, вам необходимо изменить параметры компонента urlManager. в конфиг файле

```
'components' => [
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        ['pattern' => 'product/index/id/<id: \d+>', 'route' => 'product/index'],
        ... // еще правила
    ],
]
```

]

подробности https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/runtime-routing/#url-rules